# How to find if a key already exists in my MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have codes that players can redeem for in-game goods like currency. These codes are one time codes, once they are used they are inserted into the players MySQL row on my table.

How can I check if a code already exists in a MySQL table's row?

I am not sure how to do this.

```
<?php

$code = 542345234543; 

$query = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE token = '$code'";
$database->query($query);

$database->close();

?>
```

Comment: use the SQL `count()` function

Comment: The above code should work, except that you're currently not checking the response at all. You should also use `count()`, as the above comment suggests.

Comment: i think you have solved your problem.

Comment: Slightly more efficient to use `SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE ...` rather than `SELECT *` if you're just checking to see if something exists. Assuming you're using `mysqli` then `$database->query()->num_rows()` will either be 1 or 0 depending on whether the record exists or not.

Comment: @CD001 That worked, thanks! Might want to put it as a answer I'll accept it.